# Нужны ли запятые?

Tags: пунктуация

Подскажите, пожалуйста, нужны ли здесь запятые?

Сегодня в большинстве случаев проектные институты составляют технические требования...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Запятые не нужны, так как два обстоятельства в начале предложения являются неоднородными.

Answer (score 0):

Не вижу здесь никаких оснований для знаков препинания: все слова отвечают на разные вопросы, являются разными членами предложения